# Session a variable and put under if else

Tags: php

is there something wrong with this code? When otp!= rand, page tend to show `echo "<script>alert('Too many failures. Please login again.'); location.href='login.php';</script>";` even when attempts < 3. How do I solve this? :(

```
if ($otp == $rand) {
//$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND otp='$otp'";
//$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
echo "<script>location.href='viewAccountBalance.php'</script>";
} 

else if ($otp != $rand)  {
  $_SESSION['attempts']++;
  if ($_SESSION['attempts'] < 3){
       echo "<script>alert('You have keyed in an invalid iBanking OTP. Please try again.');location.href='loginOtp.php'</script>";
  } 
  else{
       echo "<script>alert('Too many failures. Please login again.'); location.href='login.php';</script>";
  }
}
}
```

Comment: We can't tell you until you show the values of all the input variables: $otp, $rand, $_SESSION['attempts'].

Comment: when you echo the $_SESSION['attempts'] value, what do you get?

Comment: $otp either equals $rand or not, so use `else`, not `else if`

Comment: Did you `session_start()` ?

Comment: @leblma it shows "13", which I realized is the number of failed attempts. When user logout(destroy session), it shows "undefined index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me once too. I don't know this happens but this worked for me

```
$_SESSION['attempts']++;
```

to

```
$_SESSION['attempts'] = $_SESSION['attempts'] + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$_SESSION['attempts'] = $_SESSION['attempts']+1;
```